# how to refresh an Icon position without loading the full map all the time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-api-java-client

I refer to bellow Google map example.
I am trying to refresh an icon position every 10 seconds with new set of lat, lng, so every 10 secs I will pass new lat/lon so that icon moves (like moving car) 
var uluru {lat: 51.89269433333334, lng: -0.47702666666666665};

My question is: 
without loading the map every 10 secs, can we update the lat/lon of the icon every 10 secs background ? or do we have to refresh the map every 10 sec?
if yes, please let me know how .

Thanks for the help

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
           /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
          #map {
            height: 800px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
            width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
           }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
        <!--The div element for the map -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {
      // The location of Uluru
      var uluru = {lat: 51.89269433333334, lng: -0.47702666666666665};
      // The map, centered at Uluru
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: uluru});
      // The marker, positioned at Uluru
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }
        </script>
        <!--Load the API from the specified URL
        * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
        * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
        * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
        -->
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update marker on google map every x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105696/update-marker-on-google-map-every-x-seconds)

Comment: Hi @geocodezip , Thanks, I saw that one, but it was 4 years old, i was not sure after the google recept api structure change , if that code is still valid,

I was looking at another Example
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

in this one,  i can remove add icon by each click, but instead of click , can we create the Array dynamic ?
example, if we call our script, get the lat/on every 10 seconds and pass it via 

addMarker Function, will it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified this script, seems working fine

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove